# What is the problem with my code in using InnerHTML instead of document.write

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie in javascript and I tried to dispense with **document.write** and use **InnerHTML** instead according to lighthouse tips but I think I made a mistake in the code please help me solve this problem
Note: This code is responsible for fetching articles from a specific section and showing them on the main page and in articles
This is the original code

```
<script defer='defer'>
//<![CDATA[
function plist(e){document.write("<ul>");for(var r=0;r<6;r++){var t=e.feed.entry[r],a="";if(r==e.feed.entry.length)break;for(var n=0;n<t.link.length;n++)if("alternate"==t.link[n].rel){a=t.link[n].href;break}if(""!=a){var i=t.title.$t,l=t.media$thumbnail.url.replace("s72-c","s1600-rw");document.write("<li><div class='thumb'><a class='rnav-img' href='"+a+"' style='background:url("+l+") no-repeat center center;background-size:cover'></a></div><div class='rnav-conent'><h4 class='rnav-title'><a href='"+a+"'>"+i+"</a></h4></div></li>")}}document.write("</ul>")}
//]]>
</script>
<b:if cond='data:view.isLayoutMode'><div class='layoutsec' id='layoutsite'/></b:if>
<div class='category'>
 <b:section cond='data:view.isHomepage' id='section' maxwidgets='3'>
    <b:widget id='HTML4' locked='true' title='games' type='HTML' version='2' visible='true'>
      <b:widget-settings>
        <b:widget-setting name='content'>games</b:widget-setting>
      </b:widget-settings>
      <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:content'>
<div class='posts-title'>
<h2><a expr:href='data:blog.searchUrl + &quot;/label/&quot; + data:title'><data:title/></a></h2>
</div>  </b:if>
  <div class='section-hom' id='section-3'>
<script expr:src='data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:content + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;redirect=false&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=3&amp;callback=plist&quot;'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
    </b:widget>
    <b:widget id='HTML2' locked='true' title='Test' type='HTML' version='2' visible='true'>
      <b:widget-settings>
        <b:widget-setting name='content'>Test</b:widget-setting>
      </b:widget-settings>
      <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:content'>
<div class='posts-title'>
<h2><a expr:href='data:blog.searchUrl + &quot;/label/&quot; + data:title'><data:title/></a></h2>
</div>
  </b:if>
  <div class='section-hom' id='section-1'>
<script expr:src='data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:content + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;redirect=false&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=6&amp;callback=plist&quot;'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
    </b:widget>
  </b:section>
</div>
</div>
```

This code is after modification

```
  <script defer='defer'>
//<![CDATA[
function plist(e){
var sele = document.getElementsByClassName("section-hom").length;
div78 = document.createElement("ul");
div78.className = "conloader", div78.innerHTML = '<ul>'
for (let r = 0; r < sele; r++) {
{var t=e.feed.entry[r],a="";if(r==e.feed.entry.length)break;for(var n=0;n<t.link.length;n++)if("alternate"==t.link[n].rel){a=t.link[n].href;break}if(""!=a){var i=t.title.$t,l=t.media$thumbnail.url.replace("s72-c/","s400/");div79 = document.createElement("li");
div79.className = "conloader2", div79.innerHTML = '<li><div class='thumb'><a class='rnav-img' href='"+a+"' style='background:url("+l+") no-repeat center center;background-size:cover'></a></div><div class='rnav-conent'><h4 class='rnav-title'><a href='"+a+"'>"+i+"</a></h4></div>';document.createElement("li")div80.className = "conloader3", div80.innerHTML = '</li>';div81 = document.createElement("ul");div81.className = "conloader4", div81.innerHTML = '</ul>'}
//]]>
</script>
<b:if cond='data:view.isLayoutMode'><div class='layoutsec' id='layoutsite'/></b:if>
<div class='category'>
 <b:section cond='data:view.isHomepage' id='section' maxwidgets='3'>
    <b:widget id='HTML4' locked='true' title='games' type='HTML' version='2' visible='true'>
      <b:widget-settings>
        <b:widget-setting name='content'>games</b:widget-setting>
      </b:widget-settings>
      <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:content'>
<div class='posts-title'>
<h2><a expr:href='data:blog.searchUrl + &quot;/label/&quot; + data:title'><data:title/></a></h2>
</div>  </b:if>
  <div class='section-hom' id='section-3'>
<script expr:src='data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:content + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;redirect=false&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=3&amp;callback=plist&quot;'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
    </b:widget>
    <b:widget id='HTML2' locked='true' title='Test' type='HTML' version='2' visible='true'>
      <b:widget-settings>
        <b:widget-setting name='content'>Test</b:widget-setting>
      </b:widget-settings>
      <b:includable id='main'>
  <b:if cond='data:content'>
<div class='posts-title'>
<h2><a expr:href='data:blog.searchUrl + &quot;/label/&quot; + data:title'><data:title/></a></h2>
</div>
  </b:if>
  <div class='section-hom' id='section-1'>
<script expr:src='data:blog.canonicalHomepageUrl + &quot;feeds/posts/default/-/&quot; + data:content + &quot;?alt=json-in-script&amp;redirect=false&amp;start-index=1&amp;max-results=6&amp;callback=plist&quot;'/>
  </div>
</b:includable>
    </b:widget>
  </b:section>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You didn't append those created elements to anything, so they are not part of the DOM.  You need a reference to the parent element and then you can do `parentEl.appendChild(newEl)`

Comment: When you do innerHTML it is not like creating a string. It will close the elements.

Comment: Can you edit my code I would be very grateful to you I hope I didn't bother you and excuse me because I'm still new to JavaScript

Comment: What is this syntax from? `</b:section>`

Comment: On blogger templates to end the section

Comment: @James Can you edit my code I would be very grateful to you I hope I didn't bother you and excuse me because I'm still new to JavaScript